# Develop a reusable Template project in Java

Tags: java, templates, reusability

So I have some files in java That I need to reuse every time I create a new project, is there a way to create a plug-in or template project where I can include all the files Im gonna reuse and then whenever I need to use em , I have just to call that plug-in or that template project ?

Comment: Maybe a library?

Comment: A jar file? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: by building these java classes into a jar file then import that jar as library, is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Yeah , I have a certain Files That Would define a project structure (I don't want to develop em everytime Im gonna create a new project) , and Then I had to create AN Application that would include that template , and I will add other resources and files ect...

Comment: Is this in an IDE or just reusing a template in general?

Comment: Sounds like a use case for creating a Maven library.

Comment: if the answer below was helpful please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it

Answer (score 0):

- Create a project that contains only the needed java classes
- Export that project into jar file
- Import that jar (the same way as you do for any external library) into your new project and they will be included

For example, in your old project (that contains the reused classes), you have a class called `MyClass` into a package called `testPkg`. After exporting that old project into a jar file and import it as library in the new project, each time you want to use `MyClass` you have to call that class using `import testPkg.MyClass`

**PS:** make sure to not use the same names of packages into the old and new projects